# How to generate pure C/C++ header files for this swift library project?

Tags: c++, swift

After compilation, there is only one libTest.a and Test.swiftmodule. How to generate pure C/C++ header files? In order to reference this library in qt.
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean for usage with Objective-C? If so, follow this guide: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c
Otherwise you need to be more specific what is it that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @KirilS. In order to reference this library in qt.

Comment: According to QT site (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ios.html) yes, they want you to generate Objective-C bridges for your code. In that case, like I said, follow the guide above

Comment: @KirilS. Thank you.